# JavaScript double function call overrides first function call

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Before I get into details, please take a look at the live example where this problem occurs - http://jsfiddle.net/66HFU/ (Script code at the bottom of this post)

Now if you would click on any image at last row, it would display these. However if you would click on upper row images, below row images are shown.

Further investigation shows that for somewhat reason the letter called function selector elements only get binded with event listener while the firstly called functions selector elements do not.

So, I would like to know is there are any ways to make the function call independent so the latter function call does not override first one (if that would fix the problem, of-course)?

The place where the event function gets bind on the element can be found in function *f_AddEvents* first lines.

And the the main function calls that are used to initialize Light Box is at the bottom of the code like this:

```
LightBox.init({
    selector: "[data-simplbox='demo1']",
    boxId: "simplbox"
});

LightBox.init({
    selector: "[data-simplbox='demo2']",
    boxId: "simplbox",
    imageLoadStart: activityIndicatorOn,
    imageLoadEnd: activityIndicatorOff
});
```

All code:

```
;(function (window, document, undefined) {
var docElem = document.documentElement;

var DomM = (function() {
    var f_ToDOMStyle = function (p_Style) {
        return p_Style.replace(/\-[a-z]/g, function (p_Style) {
            return p_Style.charAt(1).toUpperCase();
        });
    };

    return {
        event: {
            set: function (p_Element, p_Events, p_Function) {
                var i = 0,
                    j = 0;

                p_Events = p_Events.split(" ");

                if (!p_Element.length) {
                    for (i = 0; i < p_Events.length; i++) {
                        p_Element.addEventListener(p_Events[i], p_Function, false);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (i = 0; i < p_Element.length; i++) {
                        for (j = 0; j < p_Events.length; j++) {
                            p_Element[i].addEventListener(p_Events[j], p_Function, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        css: {
            set: function (p_Element, p_Style) {
                var j;
                if (!p_Element.length) {
                    for (j in p_Style) {
                        if (p_Style.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                            j = f_ToDOMStyle(j);
                            p_Element.style[j] = p_Style[j];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < p_Element.length; i++) {
                        for (j in p_Style) {
                            if (p_Style.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                                j = f_ToDOMStyle(j);
                                p_Element[i].style[j] = p_Style[j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}());

var _LightBox = {
    f_MergeObjects: function (p_Original, p_Updates) {
        for (var i in p_Updates) {
            if (p_Updates.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                p_Original[i] = p_Updates[i];
            }
        }
        return p_Original;
    },

    f_isFunction: function (p_Function) {
        return !!(p_Function && p_Function.constructor && p_Function.call && p_Function.apply);
    },

    f_Initialize: function (p_Options) {
        var base = this;

        base.m_Options = base.f_MergeObjects(_LightBox.options, p_Options || {});
        base.m_Elements = document.querySelectorAll(base.m_Options.selector);
        base.m_ElementsLength = base.m_Elements.length - 1;
        base.m_Body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        base.m_CurrentImageElement = false;
        base.m_CurrentImageNumber = 0;
        base.m_Direction = 1;
        base.m_InProgress = false;
        base.m_InstalledImageBox = false;

        console.log(base.m_Elements);

        // Check if hardware acceleration is supported and check if touch is enabled.
        base.f_CheckBrowser();

        // Adds events.
        base.f_AddEvents();
    },

    f_CheckBrowser: function () {
        var base = this,
            isTouch = "ontouchstart" in window || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints || navigator.maxTouchPoints || false,
            vendors = ["ms", "O", "Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml"],
            rootStyle = docElem.style,
            hardwareAccelerated = false;

        if ("transform" in rootStyle) {
            hardwareAccelerated = true;
        } else {
            while (vendors.length) {
                if (vendors.pop() + "Transform" in rootStyle) {
                    hardwareAccelerated = true;
                }
            }
        }

        base.browser = {
            "isHardwareAccelerated": hardwareAccelerated,
            "isTouch": isTouch
        };
    },

    f_AddEvents: function () {
        var base = this;

        // Add open image event on images.
        for (var i = 0; i < base.m_Elements.length; i++) {
            (function (i) {
                base.m_Elements[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    console.log(base.m_Elements[i]);

                    if (base.f_isFunction(base.m_Options.onImageStart)) {
                        base.m_Options.onImageStart();
                    }

                    base.f_OpenImage(i);
                }, false);
            })(i);
        }

        // Resize event for window.
        window.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            base.f_SetImage();
        }, false);

        // Add keyboard support.
        if (base.m_Options.enableKeyboard) {
            var keyBoard = {
                left: 37,
                right: 39,
                esc: 27
            };

            window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                if (base.m_CurrentImageElement) {
                    if (base.m_InProgress) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    switch (event.keyCode) {
                        case keyBoard.left:
                            // If the previous one is out of target range then go to the last image.
                            if ((base.m_CurrentImageNumber - 1) < 0) {
                                base.f_OpenImage(base.m_ElementsLength, "left");
                            } else {
                                base.f_OpenImage(base.m_CurrentImageNumber - 1, "left");
                            }

                            return false;

                        case keyBoard.right:
                            // If the next one is out of target range then go to the first image.
                            if ((base.m_CurrentImageNumber + 1) > base.m_ElementsLength) {
                                base.f_OpenImage(0, "right"); 
                            } else {
                                base.f_OpenImage(base.m_CurrentImageNumber + 1, "right");
                            }

                            return false;

                        case keyBoard.esc:
                            base.f_QuitImage();
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }, false);
        }

        // Add document click event.
        if (base.m_Options.quitOnDocumentClick) {
            document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;

                event.preventDefault();

                if (target && target.id != "imagelightbox" && base.m_CurrentImageElement && !base.m_InProgress && base.m_InstalledImageBox) {
                    base.f_QuitImage();
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }, false);
        }
    },

    f_OpenImage: function (p_WhichOne, p_Direction) {
        var base = this,
            newFragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            newImageElement = document.createElement("img"),
            target = base.m_Elements[p_WhichOne].getAttribute("href");

        if (base.m_CurrentImageElement) {
            base.f_RemoveImage();
        }

        if (base.f_isFunction(base.m_Options.imageLoadStart)) {
            base.m_Options.imageLoadStart();
        }

        base.m_InProgress = true;
        base.m_InstalledImageBox = false;
        base.m_Direction = typeof p_Direction === "undefined" ? 1 : p_Direction == "left" ? -1 : 1;

        newImageElement.setAttribute("src", target);
        newImageElement.setAttribute("alt", "LightBox");
        newImageElement.setAttribute("id", base.m_Options.boxId);

        newFragment.appendChild(newImageElement);
        base.m_Body.appendChild(newFragment);

        base.m_CurrentImageElement = document.getElementById(base.m_Options.boxId);
        base.m_CurrentImageElement.style.opacity = "0";
        base.m_CurrentImageNumber = p_WhichOne;

        if (base.m_Options.quitOnImageClick) {
            base.f_ImageClickEvent = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                base.f_QuitImage();
            };

            base.m_CurrentImageElement.addEventListener("click", base.f_ImageClickEvent, false);
        }

        if (base.browser.isHardwareAccelerated) {
            DomM.css.set(base.m_CurrentImageElement, base.f_AddTransitionSpeed(base.m_Options.animationSpeed));
        }

        base.f_SetImage();

        DomM.css.set(base.m_CurrentImageElement, base.f_doTranslateX(50 * base.m_Direction + "px"));

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (base.browser.isHardwareAccelerated) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    DomM.css.set(base.m_CurrentImageElement, base.f_doTranslateX("0px"));
                }, 50);
            }

            if (base.f_isFunction(base.m_Options.imageLoadEnd)) {
                base.m_Options.imageLoadEnd();
            }
        }, 20);

        setTimeout(function () {
            base.m_InProgress = false;
            base.m_InstalledImageBox = true;
        }, base.m_Options.animationSpeed - 200);
    },

    f_SetImage: function () {
        var base = this,
            screenHeight = window.innerHeight || docElem.offsetHeight,
            screenWidth = window.innerWidth || docElem.offsetWidth,
            tmpImage = new Image(),
            imageWidth, imageHeight, imageSizeRatio;

        if (!base.m_CurrentImageElement) {
            return;
        }

        tmpImage.onload = function () {
            imageWidth = this.width;
            imageHeight = this.height;
            imageSizeRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

            if (Math.floor(screenWidth/imageSizeRatio) > screenHeight) {
                imageWidth = screenHeight * imageSizeRatio * 0.7;
                imageHeight = screenHeight * 0.7;
            } else {
                imageWidth = screenWidth * 0.7;
                imageHeight = screenWidth / imageSizeRatio * 0.7;
            }

            DomM.css.set(base.m_CurrentImageElement, {
                "top": ((screenHeight - imageHeight) / 2) + "px",
                "left": ((screenWidth - imageWidth) / 2) + "px",
                "width": Math.floor(imageWidth) + "px",
                "height": Math.floor(imageHeight) + "px",
                "opacity": 1
            });
        };

        tmpImage.src = base.m_CurrentImageElement.getAttribute("src");
    },

    f_RemoveImage: function () {
        var base = this;

        if (base.m_CurrentImageElement) {
            if (base.f_isFunction(base.m_Options.quitOnImageClick)) {
                base.m_CurrentImageElement.removeEventListener("click", base.f_ImageClickEvent, false);
            }

            base.m_CurrentImageElement.parentNode.removeChild(base.m_CurrentImageElement);
            base.m_CurrentImageElement = false;
        }
        return false;
    },

    f_QuitImage: function () {
        var base = this;

        if (base.m_CurrentImageElement) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                DomM.css.set(base.m_CurrentImageElement, {
                    "opacity": 0,
                    "transition": ("opacity " + base.m_Options.fadeOutSpeed + "ms ease")
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    base.f_RemoveImage();

                    if (base.f_isFunction(base.m_Options.onImageQuit)) {
                        base.m_Options.onImageQuit();
                    }

                }, base.m_Options.fadeOutSpeed);
            }, 20);
        }
    },

    f_IsValidSource: function (p_Src) {
        return new RegExp().test(p_Src);
    },

    f_doTranslateX: function (p_Pixels) {
        return {
            "-webkit-transform": "translateX(" + p_Pixels + ")",
            "-moz-transform": "translateX(" + p_Pixels + ")",
            "-o-transform": "translateX(" + p_Pixels + ")",
            "-ms-transform": "translateX(" + p_Pixels + ")",
            "transform": "translateX(" + p_Pixels + ")"
        };
    },

    f_AddTransitionSpeed: function (p_Speed) {
        var base = this;

        return {
            "-webkit-transition": "transform " + p_Speed + "ms ease, opacity " + base.m_Options.fadeInSpeed + "ms ease",
            "-moz-transition": "transform " + p_Speed + "ms ease, opacity " + base.m_Options.fadeInSpeed + "ms ease",
            "-o-transition": "transform " + p_Speed + "ms ease, opacity " + base.m_Options.fadeInSpeed + "ms ease",
            "transition": "transform " + p_Speed + "ms ease, opacity " + base.m_Options.fadeInSpeed + "ms ease"
        };
    }
};

_LightBox.options = {
    selector: "[data-imagelightbox]",
    boxId: "imagelightbox",
    allowedTypes: "png|jpg|jpeg|gif",

    quitOnImageClick: true,
    quitOnDocumentClick: true,
    enableKeyboard: true,

    animationSpeed: 750,
    fadeInSpeed: 500,
    fadeOutSpeed: 200,

    imageLoadStart: function () {},
    imageLoadEnd: function () {},
    onImageQuit: function () {},
    onImageStart: function () {}
};

LightBox.init = function (p_Options) {
    _LightBox.f_Initialize(p_Options);
};
})(window, document, window.LightBox = window.LightBox || {});

var activityIndicatorOn = function () {
    var newE = document.createElement("div"),
        newB = document.createElement("div");

    newE.setAttribute("id", "imagelightbox-loading");
    newE.appendChild(newB);
    document.body.appendChild(newE);
},
activityIndicatorOff = function () {
    var elE = document.getElementById("imagelightbox-loading");
    elE.parentNode.removeChild(elE);
};

LightBox.init({
    selector: "[data-simplbox='demo1']",
    boxId: "simplbox"
});

LightBox.init({
    selector: "[data-simplbox='demo2']",
    boxId: "simplbox",
    imageLoadStart: activityIndicatorOn,
    imageLoadEnd: activityIndicatorOff
});
```

Comment: Well, you just post an entirely lib here. Can your summarize? Show us just the relevant part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost working. What you handled badly is the fact that you can perform several init. On each init, you overwrite some items, especially with this line :

```
base.m_Elements = document.querySelectorAll(base.m_Options.selector);
```

So base.m_Elements will only have the elements of the last init.
( Based on the name 'init' i wonder if the real use case wouldn't be to allow just one call of init... )

Quick-fix is to do one single init with :

```
LightBox.init({
    selector: "[data-simplbox='demo1'],[data-simplbox='demo2']",
    boxId: "simplbox"
});
```

(erase the two calls to init)
And here it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/66HFU/1/

So i guess either you want to support several init, or (easier to maintain in fact), throw exception on multiple init and expect the lib user to write the right selector in the single init call.

Edit : Super quick fix for your issue : rather than having LightBox as a singleton, have it as a Class :

```
 function LightBox( initArguments ) {
   // something like what was done in init

 }

 LightBox.prototype = {
   f_RemoveImage : function() {
   } ,
   f_OpenImage : function( ..., ... ) {
   } ,
    ...
 }
```

then you can call with no issue :

```
var demo1LB = new LightBox({ selector: "[data-simplbox='demo1']", 
                              boxId: "simplbox" });

var demo2LB = new LightBox({ selector: "[data-simplbox='demo2']", 
                              boxId: "simplbox" });
```

Comment: Thank you and yes, I will look into better multiple init dealing way.

Comment: BTW, can you give some example of supporting several init?

Comment: In-fact I tried to solve this by making LightBox as class before I posted here. It worked with only 1 function calling because when I called it second time it gave error like: "...is not constructor".
However, now it seems working. Hmm... Anyways, thank you again! Perhaps 1 day if I see you I will buy you a beer! :D

Comment: Glad to know it's working now. If you change the beer for a glass of wine we have a deal ! Cheers.

Comment: I will remember that! Cheers to you aswell.